# Using overloaded operator (defined in a class) on another method (of the same class) (Eigen usage)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, eigen

I have a template

```
template<typename T>
struct Parameter {
private:
    bool _fixed;
    T _value;
public:
    std::string name;
    const bool* is_fixed = &_fixed;

    Parameter(std::string name, T value) : name(name), _value(value), _fixed(false) {}
    Parameter& operator=(const T& oValue){
        if (_fixed){throw std::runtime_error("Error fixed value..");}
        _value = oValue;
        return *this;
    }
    void fix() { _fixed = true; }
    void unfix() { _fixed = false; }
};
```

Where the role of `Parameter` is to basically allow for its value to be 'const-ified'/'fixed' during run time. Heres an example of its usage:

```
std::string name = "A_Vector";
Eigen::RowVectorXd value = Eigen::RowVectorXd::Ones(1);
Parameter<Eigen::RowVectorXd> param(name, value);
// I can change the value like
param = Eigen::RowVectorXd::Ones(3);
// I can fix the value
param.fix();
// If i were to attempt to redefine it throws runtime error
param = Eigen::RowVectorXd::Ones(5); // Error
```

However, in order to access Eigen methods i would need to expose the value
My work around is to define a .raw() method that returns the value
For example, I would like to access the `.array()` Eigen method and perform computations like `param.raw().array()`

Obviously this is a loop hole to the 'fixed' attribute as now i can alter the value like:

```
// I can change the value like
param = Eigen::RowVectorXd::Ones(3);
// I can fix the value
param.fix();
// Loop hole
param.raw() = Eigen::RowVectorXd::Ones(10);
```

Is it possible to redefine `.raw()` in a way that the overloaded operator (as defined in `Parameter`)  is used such that

```
param.raw() = Eigen::RowVectorXd::Ones(10);
```

Throws an error?

Comment: You can change the return type of raw so that it always return a const reference/pointer, but constness is a compile time thing, so you can not change it at runtime.

Comment: I forget something: You can overload the raw method so that it will check the fixed condition only if it is called on a non-const object. But I think the better idea is trying to rethink your design, so that you can use the compile-time const correctness.

Comment: @gerum Thanks, `const T& raw() { return _value; }` does the job. I wanted the only way the value could be changed is through `operator=` and not through `.raw()`. `.raw()` was only meant to be a 'read only' kind of method.